# How to change the meta on each page individually in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a project when the html.index file has the meta data. I.e. as follows:

```
 <meta
      property = "og: description"
      content = "This is my web."
    />
```

Then when I post a link on WhatsApp or Slack I can see the description I wrote or more correctly the "slogan of the site".
How can I change the description when on the example page on the page "My projects" When I send the link in the description will be written "My projects".
Plus, I tried using React Helemnt but it does not work for me

```
        <Helmet>
              <title>{web.title}</title>
              <description>My projects</description>
        </Helmet>
```

Where am I wrong and what am I missing?

Comment: check out `React Helmet`

Comment: I tried it but it does not work

Comment: _Why_ doesn't Helmet work for you? Knowing that may lead to solutions.

Comment: Helmet change the title of the page but when I send the page in link the title doesn't change